# Laravel 4 / Eloquent ORM: Only Objects with relational Objects

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

ive got products an articles. An article belongs to a product, so ive got the hasMany-Relationship in my product class and the belongsTo relation in my article class.

Ok now i can grab all articles of a certain product.
But what i need is the following:

I want to display only the products which got at least one article. Do i have to use a db-query for that or can i use the eloquent mechanisms for that?

Thanks in advance.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at scopes http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes for re-usable where methods. This will allow you to do:

```
Products::hasArticles()->get();
```

If you want to perform this on a relation here is an excerpt from http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships:

> If you need to add further constraints to which comments are
>   retrieved, you may call the comments method and continue chaining
>   conditions:

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', '=', 'foo')->first();
```

So instead of calling `Post::find(1)->comments` you use the full method `comments()` to get the query, which will allow you to add your own constraints to it (even a defined scope in the link mentioned above) and retrieve the data via `first()` or `get()` etc...

Comment: I was thinking to complicated. The scope functionality helped me a lot and i just needed a sql query with a join. Thanks for you answer!